# Simple Fltk application not cross-compiling with MinGW

Tags: linux, windows, g++, mingw, cross-compiling

I am trying to do cross-compiling on Linux to create exe file for 32bit Windows. I use following code:

```
i686-w64-mingw32-g++ rnfltk_simplest.cpp -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -o rnfltk_simplest.exe -lfltk -I/usr/include/
```

But I get an output with many errors:

```
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:32:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/_timeval.h:10:8: error: redefinition of ‘struct timeval’
 struct timeval
        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/select.h:47:0,
                 from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/bits/time.h:30:8: error: previous definition of ‘struct timeval’
 struct timeval
        ^~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:21:16: error: using typedef-name ‘fd_set’ after ‘struct’
 typedef struct fd_set
                ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:77:5: note: ‘fd_set’ has a previous declaration here
   } fd_set;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:25:3: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef int fd_set’
 } fd_set;
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:77:5: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef struct fd_set fd_set’
   } fd_set;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:104:16: error: using typedef-name ‘fd_set’ after ‘struct’
 typedef struct fd_set FD_SET;
                ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:77:5: note: ‘fd_set’ has a previous declaration here
   } fd_set;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:105:16: error: using typedef-name ‘fd_set’ after ‘struct’
 typedef struct fd_set *PFD_SET;
                ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:77:5: note: ‘fd_set’ has a previous declaration here
   } fd_set;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:36:0,
                 from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:106:16: error: using typedef-name ‘fd_set’ after ‘struct’
 typedef struct fd_set *LPFD_SET;
                ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:77:5: note: ‘fd_set’ has a previous declaration here
   } fd_set;
     ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/share/mingw-w64/include/windows.h:92:0,
                 from /usr/include/Fl/Fl_Window.H:26,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:4:
/usr/share/mingw-w64/include/winsock.h:299:34: error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, PTIMEVAL)’
   WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WSAAPI select(int nfds,fd_set *readfds,fd_set *writefds,fd_set *exceptfds,const PTIMEVAL timeout);
                                  ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:219:0,
                 from /usr/include/stdlib.h:275,
                 from /usr/include/FL/fl_utf8.h:36,
                 from /usr/include/FL/Fl.H:32,
                 from rnfltk_simplest.cpp:2:
/usr/include/sys/select.h:108:12: note: previous declaration ‘int select(int, fd_set*, fd_set*, fd_set*, timeval*)’
 extern int select (int __nfds, fd_set *__restrict __readfds,
            ^~~~~~
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in

```
-I/usr/include/
```

This path contains headers for libraries configured for and installed in your *Linux* system. But you want to use headers specific to the *Windows* libraries. These are installed in the MinGW compiler "system" include directory (most likely `/usr/share/mingw-w64/include` given that from there all the collisions come).

You need to install Fltk into your MinGW. For example, in openSUSE, this would be the package `mingw64-fltk-devel`.

Comment: I could not find `mingw64-fltk-devel` in debian. Probably I will have to build using script here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35238493/cross-compiling-c-code-with-mingw-on-linux-targetting-windows-error-happens or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58036647/not-able-to-make-fltk-on-mingw/58068792#58068792